# TensorFlow code help - Getting Started Example

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

I need help from someone to explain to me the code below. I'm kind of new to TensorFlow, but I have specific questions defined within code below

```
import tensorflow as tf

# Model parameters
#Why are variables initialize with .3 and -.3
W = tf.Variable([.3], dtype=tf.float32)
b = tf.Variable([-.3], dtype=tf.float32)
```

What does the x, b, W and y variables represent?

```
# Model input and output
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32) # this is the input
linear_model = W * x + b       # this is the linear_model operation
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32) # Is this the output we're trying to predict.
```

Why is the code passing in a parameter value of 0.01 to the GradientDescentOptimizer function?

```
# loss - measure how far apart the current model is from the provided data.
loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(linear_model - y)) # sum of the squares
# optimizer
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01) # Why are we passing the value '0.01'
train = optimizer.minimize(loss)
```

What does y_train represent here?

```
# training data
x_train = [1, 2, 3, 4] # the input variables we know
y_train = [0, -1, -2, -3] # 

# training loop
init = tf.global_variables_initializer() # init is a handle to the TensorFlow sub-graph that initializes all the global variables. Until we call sess.run, the variables are  unitialized
sess = tf.Session() # Sesson encapsulates the control and state of the TensorFlow runtime. ITs used to evaluate the nodes, we must run the computational graph within a session
sess.run(init) # reset values to wrong
for i in range(1000):
  sess.run(train, {x: x_train, y: y_train})
```

What does the variables curr_W, curr_b represent here?

```
# evaluate training accuracy
# Why does the variables W and b represent?
curr_W, curr_b, curr_loss = sess.run([W, b, loss], {x: x_train, y: y_train})
print("W: %s b: %s loss: %s"%(curr_W, curr_b, curr_loss))
```

The code example comes from Tensorflow website: https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/get_started#complete_program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What does the x, b, W and y variables represent?

These are symbolic variables that the model is going to use - input, output and neural network parameters.
`x` and `y` are the data, they don't change, that's why they're defined as `tf.placeholder`. `W` and `y` are learnable parameters (in TF terminology *trainable*). Initial value is less important than the dimensions of those parameters (in fact, [not exactly](https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.06422), but that's an advanced topic). In this example, both `W` and `b` are one-dimensional, though usually `W` is a matrix and `b` is a vector.

Together, all defined variables form a so called *computational graph*.

> Why is the code passing in a parameter value of 0.01 to the
>   GradientDescentOptimizer function?

This is the *learning rate*. In simple terms, it's the step size that the engine is making when it optimizes the objective function `loss`. The learning rate is usually close to 0, but exact value depends on many factors. In fact, it's one of common hyperparameters that researches try manually. `0.01` seems like a good starting point, because it's good enough in many cases.

> What does y_train represent here?

`x_train` and `y_train` are the training data, the first one is the input and the second one is the expected label. In this case, you are telling that input `1` should lead to result `0`, input `2` to `1` and so on. Hopefully, the network is going to figure out from these 4 examples that it should learn a "minus one" operation (side note: the neural networks is just a linear model that fits perfectly). It's called *supervised learning*.

> What does the variables curr_W, curr_b represent here?

First of all, note that `curr_W` and `curr_b` are ordinary python variables, while `W` and `b` are symbolic variables. Symbolic variables define how your computation is organized and they take different values during training. `curr_W` and `curr_b` are just one of those values after some iterations. Basically, you take a snapshot of the model and print it out to see what the neural network has learned. The result values `-1` and `1` (almost) mean that the neural network successfully a linear transformation.

Comment: What is the value of biases and weight in my code example?

Comment: Initial values of `W` and `b` are 0.3 and -0.3, and, as stated in the answer, it's not that important. Then, during training, these values constantly change (a good exercise - print them out on each iteration), until, in the very end, they are close to -1 and 1.

Answer (score 0):

> What does the x, b, W and y variables represent?

x are the inputs, b is the biases for those inputs, W is the weight matrix for those inputs and y are the target values for those inputs.

To train a supervised learning model like here, you need some training data. Yours is this:

```
# training data
x_train = [1, 2, 3, 4] # the input variables we know
y_train = [0, -1, -2, -3] #
```

y_train are the target values corresponding to the input values [1,2,3,4].

```
curr_W, curr_b
```

are the current weights and biases of your model, respectively, after a round of training.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. So why is y_train just the target values?

Comment: What else do you want it to be? This is a convention. x=input values and y=corresponding target values for those same inputs.

Comment: I guess what do you mean by target values? I'm a newbie to this ML

Comment: If you have an underlying function that's y=x^2 and you give your algorithm x=[1 2 3] and y=[1 4 9] it will start to learn the underlying function (with more data like this). x here are you inputs and y the target values/outputs.

Comment: Yes, that's right. Expected output that you provide the algo.

Comment: What is the value of biases and weight in my code example?